# How can I find the total flow rate at a point in time?

Tags: sql

I have ~10,000 rows of water orders, each with a Start (datetime format), End (datetime format) and Flow_rate. I need to determine the total flow rate at each 12 hour interval between two dates (e.g., 1-Nov-2023 to 8-Nov-23).

Example data below:

t_flow

| Flow_item | Start | End | Flow_rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 02_Nov-23 08:15 | 04-Nov-23 08:15 | 7 |
| 002 | 03-Nov-23 08:30 | 03-Nov-23 20:30 | 4 |
| 003 | 03-Nov-23 09:00 | 10-Nov-23 21:00 | 12 |
| 004 | 05-Nov-23 10:30 | 07-Nov-23 10:30 | 2 |

Desired output:
t_flow_total

| Interval | Total_flow |
| --- | --- |
| 01-Nov-23 11:00 | 0 |
| 01-Nov-23 23:00 | 0 |
| 02-Nov-23 11:00 | 7 |
| 02-Nov-23 23:00 | 7 |
| 03-Nov-23 11:00 | 23 |
| 03-Nov-23 23:00 | 19 |

I first created a CTE to generate datetimes for 11 AM and 11 PM between the selected dates (1 Nov to 8 Nov)

```
;WITH CTE1 AS (
SELECT DATEADD(hh, 11, '2023-11-01 00:00:00') as Interval
UNION ALL
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(hh,12,Interval) as datetime)
FROM CTE1
WHERE Interval <= '2023-11-08 11:00:00'
)

SELECT * FROM CTE1
```

This next part is where I get stuck. I don't see how to join the two tables as the datetimes don't match. The logic I think I need is to sum all order flows if:

1. Start < Interval
2. End > Interval

I think this would look something like:

```
CASE WHEN Start < Interval AND End > Interval THEN SUM(Flow_rate) AS Total_flow
```

In Excel this would be achieved with a SUMIFS statement like =SUMIFS(Flow_rate, Start, "<"&Interval, End, ">"&Interval)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why the 1 hour offset from midday and midnight?

Comment: Is the flow rate consistent between each start and end timestamp? What is the time unit for your flow rate denominator: is it e.g. litres per hour?

Comment: @Bohemian 11 AM / PM is the end of the window for a flow rate to be changed, so the total flow rate will be stable until around 12 hours later.

Comment: @NickW the flow rate is consistent between the start and end timestamp. The time unit is ML/d

Comment: Add a tag for the dbms you're using. The query is product specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a left-`join`:

```
with cte(dt) as (
   select cast('2023-11-01 11:00:00' as datetime)
   union all
   select dateadd(hour, 12, c.dt) from cte c where c.dt < '2023-11-08 11:00:00'
)
select c.dt, sum(coalesce(t.flow_rate, 0)) 
from cte c left join t_flow t on t._start <= c.dt and c.dt <= t._end
group by c.dt
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CKiWMz14)

Comment: That works, thanks!

Comment: can you give a solution to determine the total by flow_groups. E.g., if the first two flows (7 ML/d and 4 ML/d) are in area A and the the last two flows (12 and 2 ML/d) are in Area B, can two columns be added with the total flow for Area A and the total flow for Area B

Comment: Ignore above request, I figured it out.

SUM(CASE WHEN t.Area = 'A' THEN t.flow_rate ELSE 0 END) AS FlowArea_A